# ASP.NET Web Application Testing Experiences

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, testing, custom-server-controls

In our project, we have 20 simple web controls, 8 composite web controls including Ajaxable Custom Grid. And all modules are developed dependent to these controls.

And now I afraid to change a control, because it effects modules more then I think.

It's too late I know but I need to write some test cases for my controls.

I searched web and find WatiN. It look good, but I need to know is it effective ?

And also I want to hear your experiences on WatiN or other tools. If you have different solution / technic to test your web applications/core custom controls, I want to learn details, problems you faced.

Thanks for all the replies !

Comment: hi dear Canavar, is there any possibility to be in touch with you. Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+1 for [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/), works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

[Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) has been a great tool for me.  It provides an IDE in firefox to create tests manually, and has a test runner that can be fairly easily automated.  It's backed/developed by [ThoughtWorks](http://www.thoughtworks.com/) who are quite solid with their work, so it will not likely disappear anytime soon.

Some of the features of selenium:

Works with most major browsers (not sure about Google Chrome)

Support for javascript (can write cases to check javascript values)

Supports Java, C#, Ruby, Perl, PHP, & Python

Answer (score 0):

+100 for Selenium.  I used it for regression testing at my last job (a high traffic public website), and it greatly increased my confidence that a release was not going to break the site.